# Alternative to GoDaddy's ConsoliDate feature (change domain expiration date)

Tags: domains, godaddy

I've been using GoDaddy to manage about 50 domain names for a few years, but recently decided to move (probably to namecheap) because of the elephant killing incident.

One GoDaddy's feature I like a lot is Consolidate, which allows you to change the expiration date of domain names for a small fee. I've searched for a while but didn't find any other registrar that provides this feature. Does anyone know if there's a registrar that allows you to change the expiration date of domains? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dotster has this option: http://www.dotster.com/domain/sync.php

Answer (score 0):

[Name.com](https://www.name.com/) has also [Domain Expiration Sync](https://www.name.com/domain-sync-information) service that allow changing expiration date for `.com` and `.net` extensions.